# How to start and change Synth?

Tags: osc, supercollider

I'm fiddling with SuperCollider + OSC and right now i don't seem to get the proper understanding of it.

This code should do:

1. start a server
2. define a synth
3. start an instance of the synth
4. mount a listener to alter the sin frequency through remote command

```
(
Server.default = Server.internal;
s = Server.default;
s.boot;

SynthDef(\fly, { arg freq = 500;
   Out.ar(0, SinOsc.ar(freq, 0, 0.1))
}).add;

~fly = Synth.new(\fly);

OSCdef.new(
    \move,
    {arg msg;
        [msg].postln;

        ~fly.set(\freq, msg[0]);
    },
    '/move',
    nil, 57120
);
)
```

Obviously it does not work as intented. The synth is not created by running the whole script. I need to run every block by itself. Also the call in OSCDef doesn't know about the `~fly` synth: `FAILURE IN SERVER /n_set Node 1000 not found`.

Answer (score 0):

JITLib makes use of the environment variables and adds a bunch of behavior. If you want to use a plain variable and manage the Synth yourself, use one of the single-character vars [a..z] instead of `~fly`. Otherwise, you can let JITLib do its thing, in which case something like this will work:

```
(
Server.default = Server.internal;
s = Server.default;
s.boot;

~fly = { arg freq = 500;
   SinOsc.ar(freq, 0, 0.1)
};


OSCdef.new(
    \move,
    {arg msg;
        [msg].postln;

        ~fly.set(\freq, msg[0]);
    },
    '/move',
    nil, 57120
);
)
```

Reference:

- http://doc.sccode.org/Overviews/JITLib.html
- http://doc.sccode.org/Classes/Environment.html